# Debug a compiled program? c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

i am currently developing an alternate shell for windows( to be replaced with explorer).

the problem is the program runs fine when run as a normal executable.

but when i set it as default shell for windows and re-log in into my user account the program runs for a few seconds and then it force closes.

is there anything i can do what might be going wrong?

BTW working on c# wpf.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger before it crashes? If there's not enough time, you can always add a `Sleep` temporarily...

Comment: What happened if you kill explorer from the task manager and run your shell?

Comment: Does the windows application log tell you anything? Usually there's a bit of stack trace hiding out there.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET i've already tried debug program that **isn't** compiled..(as i've specified in the question).... can u plz elaborate "attach to process"...yes i'm new to c#..thnx fr ur help

Comment: @spender if i run from taskmanager.. it runs fine.... but if i set it as default shell program in regedit.. it runs for a few seconds then it crashes

Comment: @BradleyDotNET thanks for the info i'll try that and reply here..

Comment: @BradleyDotNET thanks for the help.. i figured out the problem..

Comment: putting on hold after the question is resolved???????

yes the problem can be reproduced and readers can benefit from the answer see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *always* debugging a compiled program.

However, when you run it from Visual Studio, the debugger is automatically attached (so you can see exceptions, set breakpoints, etc).

You *can* do the same thing to an already running process by using the "Attach to Process" option in the "Debug" menu.

Other things to try:

- Add try/catch blocks around areas that can blow up
- Add logging, especially to the try/catch blocks
- Put a "sleep" at startup if the program closes before you can attach the debugger.

Also, from @ScottChamberlin, you can directly ask that a debugger be attached from the running executable via `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()`.

Comment: One other thing you can try, do a `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` and it will ask you which version of visual studio do you want to open and start debugging like you did attach to process.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I had no idea you could do that. Thanks for the tip! I edited it in.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You probably never developed any windows services as that's usually the very first line of code whenever your service fails to start...

Comment: @DeanKuga Actually I have; and yes, thats very difficult to debug. To handle such cases; I put a try/catch and logging around the startup process.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I guess now you know better :) Debugger.Launch() is a much, much easier approach to figure out why your service won't start...

Comment: @DeanKuga I'll bet. I'll definitely try that next time my startup code blows up.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain although i got my problem solved with inserting try-catch blocks in several pieces of code.... but i also tried to use `Debugger.Launch()` but it doesn't seems to work?? as specified it doesn't ask which version of visual studio do i want to open.